# Convert a MAUI-C# control to xaml-string

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

i know i can load a control from xaml-code like this:

```
string navigationButtonXAML = "<Button Text=\"Navigate\" />";
Button navigationButton = new Button().LoadFromXaml(navigationButtonXAML);
```

But is it possible to covert my C# control to xaml, in the end it should look somehow like this:

```
string myControl = new MyControl.WriteToXAML();
```

Comment: No, there is no such feature. I doubt it would be possible for the feature to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is it possible to covert my C# control to xaml, in the end it should look somehow like this: `string myControl = new MyControl.WriteToXAML();`

No, it can't covert C# control to xaml in MAUI or Xamarin.

I tested the code and searched related content about it, but there is no workaround to achieve it.

For more info about XAML, you can refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/?view=net-maui-7.0).